# Jquery top undefined for anchor target

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add some off set to the top of an anchor, so it will not be hidden behind a fixed header.
But I keep getting a top `undefined` error.

This is my scenario:
My page has a `div` that uses the scrollbar plugin to scroll instead of the browser's one.
That `div` class is `main-content-container`.

I also create the anchors automatically using the [autoAnchor jquery Plugin](http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/autoanchors.php).
What I am trying to accomplish is to get the link to actually move about 100px above the target when clicked.

Here is jQuery code I have so far, that always gives me "top" undefined.

```
$(".autoanchors a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetpos = $($(this).attr('href')).position(); // note this line
  var scrollpos = targetpos.top - 100;
  $('.main-content-container').scrollTo(0,scrollpos);
});
```

Since i am using auto anchor i cannot do with the css version of "margin-top:-100px" because it references the id of the title and if i move that with css is not longer in the position i need it to be.

I am not sure if I explained this correctly.
Let me know if I need to explain it a bit further.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `$(this).attr('href')` supposed to return? `myId` or `#myId` ?

Comment: yes it is suppose to return the id.

Comment: With or without the `#` ? console.log() it if not sure. It may also be ""undefined".

Comment: it returns the id with `#` which then we use to get the position of the element on the page. And using `console.log` it does that just fine, but if i `console.log` that with `.position();` then i get undefined.

Comment: I am not sure of this but does `.position()` works in relation to the `body` of the document? because i have to get the position base on another `div` that scrolls since the `body` never moves.

Comment: Have you tried `$($(this).attr('href')).offset()` ? It also returns top and left.

Comment: after trying so much i found a solution via css instead that works. `:target:before {
    content: "" !important;
    display: block !important;
    height: 100px !important;
    /* fixed header height*/
    margin: -100px 0 0 !important;
    /* negative fixed header height */
}` thanks for the help.